# How can i iterate through a list of maps so that i get the end value all the way?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So i have a list of maps(currently with one value) ...each value in the list is a map with a string as a key and a list(of maps (with a string key and string value)) as the value....I am trying to get the each value for for the keys i.e. imgpath and error

However , i get null .....How can i don't this??..[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKlZQ.png)

```
class _ErrorsCapturedState extends State<ErrorsCaptured> {
  Widget _createError(BuildContext context, index) {
    String imgpath;
    String error;
    List<Map<String, Map>> errorInfo = [
  {
    'Transmitter': {
      'imgpath':null,
          // 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTh-U8FgtxrN0Zcgs4ETPKGtxBUbqmncDQlh5IYcGT5bxsDi92a',
      'error': 'Transmitter error detected'
    },
  },
  {
    'Antenna': {
      'imgpath':null,
          // 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTh-U8FgtxrN0Zcgs4ETPKGtxBUbqmncDQlh5IYcGT5bxsDi92a',
      'error': 'Antenna error detected'
    },
  },
  {
    'Uninterrupted': {
      'imgpath':null,
          // 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTh-U8FgtxrN0Zcgs4ETPKGtxBUbqmncDQlh5IYcGT5bxsDi92a',
      'error': 'Obvious error detected'
    },
  },
  {
    'Satellite receiver': {
      'imgpath':null,
          // 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTh-U8FgtxrN0Zcgs4ETPKGtxBUbqmncDQlh5IYcGT5bxsDi92a',
      'error': 'another error detected'
    },
  },
  // 'Antenna System',
  // 'U.P.S',
  // 'Satellite Receiver',
  // 'Mains Power',
]

    errorInfo.map(
      (value) {
        print(errorInfo);
        imgpath = index[value]['imgpath'];
        error = index[value]['error'];
      },
    );
    var imgcreated;
    if (imgpath != null) {
      imgcreated = Image.network(
        imgpath,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      );
    } else {
      imgcreated = Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/flat.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      );
    }

    var text;
    if (error != null) {
      text = Text('$error');
    } else {
      text = Text('No errors found!');
    }
    var sizedBox = SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    );
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 20.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          width: 300,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                centerTitle: false,
                expandedHeight: 200,
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace:
                    FlexibleSpaceBar(title: text, background: imgcreated),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Placeholder(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        shadowColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's no clear whether `errorInfo` will *always* contain 1 item. If not, the rest of your code doesn't really make sense. Please tell me if that's the case.

Comment: check the edited question....i used null on image path to make it easier to read

Comment: I don't quite understand what you achieve with `errorInfo.map()` because you constantly override the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you don't need to use `.map()`, you could do this:

```
imgpath = errorInfo[index].values.first['imgpath'];
error = errorInfo[index].values.first['error'];
```